# Cors issues with Font

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, fonts, cors

Currently having some cors policy issues on a wordpress website.

I tried editing htaccess. Kind of copy-paste as follows 
But it turns out not working .I am new to wordpress and only here for maintanance.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
      SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"



Access to font at 'https://interiorsfurniture.com/assets/themes/bridge-child/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'https://www.interiorsfurniture.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: I know it's not solution you are searching for, but as plan B you can always download font file and upload it to your server and avoid this problem.

Comment: On a FilesMatch note, remove those `ttf`, `ttc`, `otf` and `eot` extensions. ttf/otf are  _system_ fonts, not web fonts. We have woff/woff2 for the stripped down and compressed specifically-for-web-use format already; ttc has _never_ been supported in browsers because it's an opaque collection and CSS already lets you define those transparently using separate font assets for specific {family/weight/style/etc} tuples, and eot died in 2016 when MS killed off IE8 (and good riddance, too).